# Increment id within a parent entity in Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have this problem where I have a parent model `User` that is one-to-many linked to another model say `Device`.

What I want to do is within each `user`, I want to create and increment an id for each `device` he own.

Something like user A have two devices so his `user_device_id` will be 1 and 2. user B have one device so his `user_device_id` will be 1. vice versa.

I have a current working solution but I am looking for an alternative solution.

The `Device` model currently implemented which overrides save method:

```
class Device(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_device_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=false)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            within_user_device_id = Device.objects.filter(user=self.user).latest('user_device_id').user_device_id
            self.user_device_id = within_user_device_id + 1
        except Device.DoesNotExist:
            self.user_device_id = 1
```

For the neater method, in my mind, to create a function that gets the current instance of `user` and use the default in `models.PositiveIntegerField` to increment this value.

The problem is I cannot get refer the current instance and call the function in `default`.

```
class Device(models.Model):

    def increment_within_user_device_id(self):
        within_user_device_id = Device.objects.filter(user=self.user).latest('user_device_id').user_device_id
        if not within_user_device_id:
            return 1
        else:
            within_user_device_id += 1
            return within_user_device_id

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # I cannot pass the function in default
    user_device_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=increment_with_user_device_id(self), null=false)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: My advice is to not complicate it. If your code works well and this type of identification is necessary, your code is fine as it is, maybe document better what it does and that is it. I think in the default argument you can't use anything that is related to the model instance (e.g. the user attribute).